# The same javascript Object with ajax call - I need it twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Please, can you explain me why this code does not work as I aspected?

I have a web page with two list containers, one it's for tickets that are opened and the other one is for tickets that are closed.

I use handlebars with a simple table template to inject in the list container.

I have defined a Ticket object, and in fetchList I make an ajax call to retrive the tickets. This is the code:

```
var Ticket = {
init : function(config){
    this.config = config;
    this.setupTemplates();
},

setupTemplates: function(){
    this.config.listTemplate = Handlebars.compile( this.config.listTemplate );
},

fetchList: function(){
    self = Ticket;

    $.ajax({
        type : self.config.ajaxType,
        dataType : 'json', 
        url: self.config.ajaxUrl,
        data: self.config.ajaxData
    }).done(function(data, status, obj) {

        self.config.listContainer.empty();

        if ( data[0] ) {
            self.config.listContainer.html( self.config.listTemplate(data) );
        } else {
            self.config.listContainer.html('<p class="lead">No ticket was found.</p>');
        }
    }).fail(function(data) {
            self.config.listContainer.html('<p class="lead text-danger">Sorry! Something went wrong!!</p>');
    });
}
```

}

Now, I post step-by-step code to show my problem.
If I focus only on one of list container, the code in the page works perfectly, for example:

```
Ticket.init({
    ajaxUrl : ajax_url,
    ajaxType : "GET",
    ajaxData : {'contact_id':contact_id, 'status':'1'},
    listTemplate: $('#tickets_list_template').html(),
    listContainer: $('.tickets_open'),
});

Ticket.fetchList();
```

This code works perfectly, it fills the right list container with the table full of tickets with status open. Wow!

Now, I want to do the same for the tickets that are closed. 
So I've tried adding this:

```
Ticket.init({
    ajaxUrl : ajax_url,
    ajaxType : "GET",
    ajaxData : {'contact_id':contact_id, 'status':'0'},
    listTemplate: $('#tickets_list_template').html(),
    listContainer: $('.tickets_close'),
});

Ticket.fetchList();
```

So the code become:

```
Ticket.init({
    ajaxUrl : ajax_url,
    ajaxType : "GET",
    ajaxData : {'contact_id':contact_id, 'status':'1'},
    listTemplate: $('#tickets_list_template').html(),
    listContainer: $('.tickets_open'),
});

Ticket.fetchList();

Ticket.init({
    ajaxUrl : ajax_url,
    ajaxType : "GET",
    ajaxData : {'contact_id':contact_id, 'status':'0'},
    listTemplate: $('#tickets_list_template').html(),
    listContainer: $('.tickets_close'),
});

Ticket.fetchList();
```

As you can see, the only thing that change is the data for the ajax request (status=0) and the list container (.tickets_close).

Now, the .tickets_open is blank, and .ticket_close return right, with the tickets that are closed.

I thought that the second ajax call returns before the first one, and I've changed the container before the first fetchList has finished.

So I tried to declare two variables, like this:

```
var ticketOpened = Ticket;
var ticketClosed = Ticket;

ticketOpened.init({
    ajaxUrl : "<?=base_url('ajax/tickets/get_tickets')?>",
    ajaxType : "GET",
    ajaxData : {'contact_id':contact_id, 'status':'1'},
    listTemplate: $('#tickets_list_template').html(),
    listContainer: $('.tickets_open'),
});

ticketOpened.fetchList();

ticketClosed.init({
    ajaxUrl : "<?=base_url('ajax/tickets/get_tickets')?>",
    ajaxType : "GET",
    ajaxData : {'contact_id':contact_id, 'status':'0'},
    listTemplate: $('#tickets_list_template').html(),
    listContainer: $('.tickets_close'),
});

ticketClosed.fetchList();
```

But .... nothing changed. Only ticket closed are right, and .ticket_open is blank. WHY?

I'm still learning javascript code concept and I can't get it.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Since `Ticket` is stateful you will need two objects. I suggest to look into constructor functions. Because Ajax is **asynchronous** `fetchList` does not wait until the Ajax request is complete. It returns immediately and you are overriding the config with the second `init` call. There are hundreds of question about Ajax here, have a look at them,

Comment: I know that ajax needs attention, and I know the problem with asynchronous ... But I think that my problem here is more on the correct usage of objects in javascript. I'd like to reuse code and probably this isn't the right way. I could solve probably creating a trigger when ajax has done and wait the trigger before call the second init ... I'd like to know if this is the right way for a clean and reusable code.

Comment: Within fetchlist(), put a console.log statement to see if  it is being called for both Tickets objects. I think there could be different problems. Without seeing more of your code for fetchlist() perhaps, itll be hard to figure out. Also are there any console errors? Also have you tried var ticket1 = new Ticket(); var ticket2 = new Ticket()?

Comment: No errors in console, and yes I put a lot of console.log inside fetchList(). Seems all right. For example ... if I put some html code inside each container, the fetchList post the content of the first and the second (that are different). So 2 calls, with chrome dev tool I see the 2 ajax call with right params too.

I've tried to use new Ticket() but return error.

Comment: I think this should help, you need different instances for each of your ticket so what when you change the attributes, it won't affect the other: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#The_class

Comment: *"I've tried to use new Ticket() but return error."* You can only use `new` with constructor functions (see my first comment). Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Custom_objects . As I said, you need **two** `Ticket` objects (of course with different variable names), not a single one. Constructor functions allow you to create multiple objects that have the same shape.